# While making and Android SDK, is there a way to constantly update the developer with a value without them passing in a view?

Tags: java, android, android-library

I'm making an Android SDK and want to expose a timer to the developer. I want to be in full control of the timer, for instance when to start it, stop it, etc.

One of the solutions I thought of is if the developer passes in a TextView, I could constantly change the text of the TextView with the timer's count. Is there any way I can expose this count as a value instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the way to handle situations like this is to use a callback interface.

Simply create a callback interface like so:

```
public interface TimerListener {
    void getTimerTick(long time);
}
```

Then add this interface as a global field in your class that holds your timer, including a way to 'set' this interface... for example:

```
public class Timer {
    ...
    private TimerListener listener;
    ...
    public setTimerListener(TimerListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, at specific parts of your code, you simply have to call

```
if(listener != null)
    listener.getTimerTick(time);
```

with the *time* being the value that is passed to you through your timer. By specific parts of the code, I mean when your Timer provides a time. For example, if you were using a `CountDownTimer` you would place that listener code within the `onTick()` method.

This way, when a developer uses your SDK, if they're interested in getting the timer tick, they simply have to write something like:

```
customTimer.setTimerListener(new TimerListener(){
    @Override
    public void getTimerTick(long time){
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(time));
    }
});
```

With callback interfaces, you'll be able to provide the developer with the timer value if they're interested, and they'll be able to use it in their TextViews, logs, or any other kind of calculations they want with their value.

I would advise against passing in a TextView, because Views are something that shouldn't be passed around carelessly. Instead of them passing you a View for your SDK to work on, you're much better off providing the developer with the values they should use to work on instead.